# Different elements linked to the same page

Tags: website-design, ux-integration

I received wireframes for a website from a client and there are small blocks with heading, little text and a button. The wireframe docs state that all those three elements must lead to the same page. The site will have mobile and desktop views.

Now I'm not a UX specialist, I'm a web developer, but I think that is a very bad idea. I think only a button must be a link. As a user I would be confused why all those elemets are clickable and where do they lead.

Can I tell that my client?

[image]

Comment: Could you please post visual snippet for better Understanding

Comment: @Grafix Guru, here you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can **show** your client the very issue you explained (all elements being clickable = BAD), I think he/she will understand why it is a bad idea.

This means implementing a rough prototype to **demo** that functionality. When your client goes to test it, he/she will hopefully see how *annoying* it is when accidentally clicking on any other element than the explicit button to navigate to that page.

Of course, explaining all of this depends on your particular client. If they are somewhat reasonable and open-minded, maybe you just need to clearly explain the scenarios that demonstrate why all elements being clickable can be bad. If he/she can make a legitimate argument for keeping that functionality or simply wants to keep it despite your advice, then hey, that's on them.

Answer (score 1):

You are right; this is a bad idea not only UX wise but even later at tracking and analytics.

From the user perspective, this approach isn't user friendly since the user would most likely accidentally click somewhere on the page only to be redirected to a page he isn't interested in. This would be frustrating for any user.

From the client side, it would be more difficult to track goal conversions, and even bounce rate (which I'd suspect would be higher since the user would be redirected to a page without probably even having the chance to explore the homepage first).
So perhaps if you'd explain from a client's perspective (not only the user's) and explain how this could impact negatively in the future, they might be more open to hear your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a grid of products on an online store. Each item shows an image, a product name, and a brief description. In that case you'd want at least the image and name to both link to the product, right? (But maybe not the description.) It seems that your situation is similar.